# ANdroid: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid path: /storage/extSdCard

Tags: java, android, exception, android-external-storage

I am trying to get External memory size. My code is running perfectly on Lollipop and Below but give exception of invalid path  on Marshmallow and above 
my code is here

```
 public static String getExternalPath(){

    String sSDpath = null;
    File   fileCur = null;
    for( String sPathCur : Arrays.asList("MicroSD", "external_SD", "sdcard1", "ext_card", "external_sd", "ext_sd", "external", "extSdCard", "externalSdCard")) // external sdcard
    {

        fileCur = new File( "/mnt/", sPathCur);
        if( fileCur.isDirectory() && fileCur.canWrite())
        {
            sSDpath = fileCur.getAbsolutePath();
            break;
        }
        if( sSDpath == null)  {
            fileCur = new File( "/storage/", sPathCur);
            if( fileCur.isDirectory() && fileCur.canWrite())
            {
                sSDpath = fileCur.getAbsolutePath();
                break;
            }
        }
        if( sSDpath == null)  {
            fileCur = new File( "/storage/emulated", sPathCur);
            if( fileCur.isDirectory() && fileCur.canWrite())
            {
                sSDpath = fileCur.getAbsolutePath();
                //Log.e("path",sSDpath);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    fileCur = new File( "/storage/extSdCard");

    return fileCur.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

And i call this function in my Activity

```
 public static String getExternalTotalMemory() {
    StatFs statFs2 = new StatFs(getExternalPath());
    long blockSize2 = statFs2.getBlockSize();
    final long totalSize2 = statFs2.getBlockCount() * blockSize2;;
    return  formatSize(totalSize2);
}
```

Comment: you can put for 23+ runtime permission so you can ref this https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: @HarshitTrivedi i did already did this but i am getting same thing

Comment: I used this code to get permissions         ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Main_Booster.this,
                new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE,android.Manifest.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES,
                        android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS,android.Manifest.permission.BATTERY_STATS,android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,
                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                },
                1);

Comment: Once check manually by going into App settings, that storage settings is ON

Comment: Why you didn't use  Environment.getExternalStoreage() ? Or you need sdcards and usb storage devices?

Answer (score 0):

In marshmallow and above version the path of external sdcard is change so it gives you error.

You need to search your external sdcard at this location.

/storage/emulated/0